# List of irreducible representations whose weights are in a single Weyl group orbit

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a (finite dimensional) simple (nonabelian) Lie algebra
over $\mathbb C$. I need a complete list of irreducible (nontrivial) representations $V$
of $\mathfrak g$ such that the Weyl group of $\mathfrak g$ acts transitively on  weights of $V$.

It is obvious that for any given $\mathfrak g$, one can list all such $V$. 
But I don't know whether it is possible to give a complete list.
The examples I have are the natural actions of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ on $\mathbb C^n$.

This question may looks unnatural to experts in Lie algebra. The reason I need it is to solve a problem in homogeneous dynamics and those $V$ are bad cases. I believe I can handle the example I give above, but in general if there are too many of them I am not sure whether I can handle them or not.

Comment: Google for cominuscule representations.

Comment: As Sasha points out, this is all standard material.   You might also search the Math Overflow pages for questions involving the term "minuscule".

Comment: @ Sasha: Thanks, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @ronggang: The usual term is "minuscule" (though "cominuscule" also occurs in some contexts).   See the explicit entry in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minuscule_representation  (but note that the concept comes originally from Bourbaki and others).   There is also a recent monograph by Richard Green: Combinatorics of minuscule representations. 
Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, 199. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2013

Comment: I'm definitely in favor of these being the minuscule representations of $G$, which are the cohomology groups of the cominuscule flag manifolds of the Langlands dual group $G^L$. The co- is for the Langlands duality. (The minuscule flag manifolds are also important; they're the ones that Hodge-degenerate to Stanley-Reisner schemes of order complexes of Bruhat order. I don't know any reason to look at the irreps associated to cominuscule fundamental weights.)